# Retrieving the selected radio button in an alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Goal:
Retrieve the selectedId of the checked radio button in alertdialog.

Problem:
You cannot retrieve the value by using findViewByid in method     SpinnerDialogItemSelected because I get a error message that is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object
>   reference

How do you retrieve the value that can be used as a argument in method SpinnerDialogItemSelected?

Info:
*I'm new in Android
*I'm using android studio

Thank you!

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/alertFormElements2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="alertFormElements2"
            android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

form_elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgtest1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="test1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="test1" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="131dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

MainActivity.java

```
package com.jfdimarzio.t1;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    private int _data = 0;


    /*
     * Show AlertDialog with some form elements.
     */
    public void alertFormElements2(View vdf) {

        dddd();
    }


    private void dddd()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View formElementsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_elements2,null, false);

        String[] vvalue = new String[]{
                "7",
                "3",
                "6",
                "3",
                "8",
                "9",
                "15",
                "11",
                "57"
        };


        final Spinner _spinner = formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, vvalue);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        _spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        // the alert dialog
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setView(formElementsView)
                .setTitle("Form Elements")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SpinnerDialogItemSelected(_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();

    }


    private void SpinnerDialogItemSelected(String value)
    {
        RadioGroup myRadioGroup  = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgtest1);
        int selectedId = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    }


} // Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RadioGroup myRadioGroup  = (RadioGroup) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.rgtest1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try passing the view you inflated programmatically to:

```
 private void SpinnerDialogItemSelected(String value, View formElementsView)
 { 
    RadioGroup myRadioGroup  = (RadioGroup) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.rgtest1);
    int selectedId = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 }
```

Comment: The value is null in formElementsView when I use this code "SpinnerDialogItemSelected(_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), findViewById(R.id.rgtest1));"

Answer (score 0):

in `activity_main.xml` you do not have the `@id/rgtest1` `RadioGroup` that's why findById returns null. After you create `formElementsView` you should find the RadioGroup in it and store it and reuse it later.

```
radioGroup  = (RadioGroup) formElementsView.findViewById(R.id.rgtest1);
```

The `View`'s hierarchy of the AlertDialog that you created is not going to be attached to the `View`'s hierarchy of the `Activity` as it looks like you are assuming. That's just not the way Android works.

Comment: Not supposed to have rgtest in activity_main.xml

Comment: It is supposed to retrieve the value rgTest from the xml form_elements

Comment: It does not work like that. `findViewById` in the activity will look for the view in its hierarchy not in the layout of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement OnCheckedChangeListener() of radiogroup.. then you can in the onClick() method of the OnCheckedChangeListener().. save it(in something like SharedPreferences may be) and reuse it.

try this code snippet:

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    SharedPref sharedPref;
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(getContext());


radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(newRadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
   {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    RadioButton radioButton = group.findViewById(checkedId);
    int id=radioButton.getId();
    sharedPref.someMethod(id);

}
});
```

Comment: Do you have a sample using OnCheckedChangeListener? it is easier to understand.